# How to fix several database contexts in asp scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a hosted service which uses a DB context, and a scoped service that also uses a DB context. It looks more or less like this

```
public class HostedWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public HostedWorker(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var database = scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
            var entity = database.GetSomeEntity();
            scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<ISomeScopedService>()
                .DoSomethingWithTheEntity(entity)
        }
    }
}

public class SomeScopedService: ISomeScopedService
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext context;

    public SomeScopedService(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithTheEntity(SomeEntity entity)
    {
        // the context doesn't track the entity
    }
}
```

The scoped service gets the database context from the dependency injection, and it turns out, it's not the same context as I get directly from the ServiceProvider. The result is, the DB context from the scoped service doesn't track the entities which I get from the context in the hosted service.

In all the other cases the context is the same: several scoped services which get the database through DI all share the same context, as well as when I pass the manually-created scope between singleton services, all of them get the same context through `GetRequiredService`. Only when I try to mix I get this result.

Is there any way to get the same DB context throughout the scope?

**UPD** The error ended up being unrelated to the DB context (which is indeed the same for different services in the scope), but I will leave the question here, since the answer may be helpful for some other cases.

Comment: What is the lifetime of `ISomeScopedService`?

Comment: `it turns out, it's not the same context as I get directly from the ServiceProvider` that's exactly how it should be. DbContexts are like connections, they shouldn't leave any longer than needed. They're roughly equivalent to a Unit-Of-Work.

Comment: Moreover whenever you are making a new scope and getting a new instance of Db it will begin a separate transaction.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just going by the example code (and assuming that everything is properly registered), it is the same service scope though so it should resolve the same database context.

Comment: 1:DbContext are not meant to be used as singletons.  2:Scoped Service should not be sharing instances since it is "scoped"

Comment: @poke that was my innate reaction to global/singleton connections and contexts. We don't know how the DbContext was actually registered. I suspect this is an XY problem. A failed update in `DoSomethingWithTheEntity`? A detached entity?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, fully agreed. I also reacted directly to some of the wording in the question (hence my answer) because just judging from the code, it should just work. But then again, the code in the question is just _“more or less like”_ that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's not the same context as I get directly from the ServiceProvider

First of all, you should never retrieve a database context directly from the service provider. You always should get it within a service scope, otherwise you will end up with a database context and a connection that won’t be disposed for the lifetime of your application.

So you should always consume database contexts within service scopes. This is done implicitly within the request pipeline (e.g. in controllers) but in hosted services, you will have to create the service scope yourself. You should also make sure that you don’t keep that scope open for a long period of time; it’s better to design your services so that they only access the database for a very limited amount of time and have multiple short-living service scopes instead of one long-living scope.

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var database = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
    var entity = database.GetSomeEntity();
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeScopedService>()
        .DoSomethingWithTheEntity(entity)
}
```

Assuming that `ISomeScopedService` is properly registered as a scoped dependency, this code should resolve the same database context instance. Database contexts are registered as scoped dependencies (by default) and thus this should resolve the same instance from both the scoped service provider and the constructor injection in your scoped service.

If this does not work for you, then your actual code probably looks different, uses different scopes (or no scopes), or the logic behind `GetSomeEntity()` retrieves a non-tracking entity.

Comment: "and thus this should resolve the same instance from both the scoped service provider and the constructor injection in your scoped service." Well, this is already a relieve :) I was afraid there was something I didn't fully understand with the DB-scopes in asp. I will start finding an error somewhere else then.